# Application.properties taking previous database instead of new one

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, eclipse

I am using spring boot application in this previously, I had different database and now I am using new database within the same sql server means both this databases is in the same sql server but when I am trying to running my project with new database in the same sql server I am getting Invalid object name CorporateData error but I am not using this database i want to use xyz database. I am also tried to clear cache of browser and eclipse both and application.properties is also right.

I want to connect my project to new database without any error.

Comment: try in terminal , `mvn clean package spring-boot:run`

Comment: is it also useful for eclipse?

Comment: You can run this command by, right click on project -> Run As -> maven build and then type your command.  for this problem you can try with restarting the project.

Comment: @Rushikesh just for make sure , what is the problem. just like  @Vishal mention `project -> Run As -> maven build`